# Eliminar un usuario mediante un input radio de los resultados de un formulario de busqueda php, al recargar al eliminar pierde el radio seleccionado

Tags: javascript, php, html

Esta parte de mi proyecto se trata de un formulario de búsqueda de usuarios en el cual en los resultados incluyo un radio para poder seleccionar uno de los resultados y borrarlo. El problema está que al borrar no consigo capturar el valor del radio seleccionado. La página se recarga pero después de poner unos alert para ver el valor capturado veo que no coge dicho valor. Si alguien pudiera guiarme y decirme que estoy haciendo mal lo agradecería.

Código de ejemplo:

```php
<?php
    //Iniciamos sesion y le damos nombre (opcional)
    session_name("parkingCentro");
    session_start();
    //Controlamos que variable esté establecida

    if (isset($_SESSION['rol'])) {
        //Si la sesion está establecida, en funcion de si es administrador o usuario redirigimos
        if ($_SESSION['rol'] != "admin") {
            header("Location: login.php");
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/fabicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/general.js"></script>
        <title>Buscar Usuarios</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        //Variables con los valores a mostrar en el menú y los links de la cabecera y el pie
        $link1 = "gestUsu.php";
        $link2 = "gestReservas.php";
        $link3 = "gestPlazas.php";
        $link4 = "cerrarSesion.php";
        $pieLink1 = "contacto.php";
        $pieLink2 = "planos.php";
        $pieLink3 = "pdfUsuarios.php";
        $pieLink4 = "empresa.php";
        $descrip1 = "Gestión de usuarios";
        $descrip2 = "Gestión de reservas";
        $descrip3 = "Gestión de plazas";
        $descrip4 = "Desconectar";
        $descripPie1 = "Contacto";
        $descripPie2 = "Planos de planta";
        $descripPie3 = "PDF Usuarios";
        $descripPie4 = "Empresa";
        include("cabecera.php");
        ?>
        <main>
            <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['nombre_usu'] ?></h1>
            <h2>Busqueda de usuarios</h2>
            <!-- Formulario de busqueda -->
            <!-- <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" id="busqueda"> -->
            <form action="eli.php" method="POST" id="busqueda">
                <div>
                    <label class="icono" for="codigo"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmarks-lines"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" placeholder="Buscar por código" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="icono" for="nombre"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-signature"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Buscar por nombre" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label class="icono" for="matricula"><i class="fa-solid fa-car-side"></i></label>
                    <input type="text" name="matricula" id="matricula" placeholder="Buscar por matrícula" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Buscar</button>
           
            <?php
            //Incluimos el archivo de conexión a la BBDD
            include('base_de_datos.php');
            //Comprobamos si se han enviado datos del formulario con el radio seleccionado para borrar usuario
            if (!isset($_POST['radioBorra'])) {
                //Si se ha establecido alguno de los campos de busqueda
                if (isset($_REQUEST["codigo"]) || isset($_REQUEST["nombre"]) || isset($_REQUEST["matricula"])) {
                    //Guardamos en variables los valores recogidos del formulario y en función de cual sea creamos el SQL
                    if (isset($_REQUEST["codigo"]) && $_REQUEST["codigo"] != "") {
                        //Creamos la SQL con la consulta
                        $sql = "select * from usuarios where cod_usuario like '%" . $_REQUEST["codigo"] . "%' LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
                        //Esta consulta es para saber el numero de resultados para la paginación
                        $contResul = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT count(*) AS conteo FROM usuarios where cod_usuario like '%" . $_REQUEST["codigo"] . "%'");
                        //Contador para la paginación
                        $conteo = $contResul->fetchObject()->conteo;
                    }
                    if (isset($_REQUEST["nombre"]) && $_REQUEST["nombre"] != "") {
                        //Creamos la SQL con la consulta
                        $sql = "select * from usuarios where nombre like '%" . $_REQUEST["nombre"] . "%' LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
                        //Esta consulta es para saber el numero de resultados para la paginación
                        $contResul = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT count(*) AS conteo FROM usuarios where nombre like '%" . $_REQUEST["nombre"] . "%'");
                        //Contador para la paginación
                        $conteo = $contResul->fetchObject()->conteo;
                    }
                    if (isset($_REQUEST["matricula"]) && $_REQUEST["matricula"] != "") {
                        //Creamos la SQL con la consulta
                        $sql = "select * from usuarios where matricula like '%" . $_REQUEST["matricula"] . "%' LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
                        //Esta consulta es para saber el numero de resultados para la paginación
                        $contResul = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT count(*) AS conteo FROM usuarios where matricula like '%" . $_REQUEST["matricula"] . "%'");
                        //Contador para la paginación
                        $conteo = $contResul->fetchObject()->conteo;
                    }
                    // Cuántos usuarios mostrar por página
                    $usuariosPorPagina = 5;
                    // Por defecto es la página 1; pero si está presente en la URL, tomamos esa
                    $pagina = 1;
                    if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) {
                        $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
                    }
                    // El límite es el número de usuarios por página
                    $limit = $usuariosPorPagina;
                    // El offset es saltar X usuarios que viene dado por multiplicar la página - 1 * los usuarios por página
                    $offset = ($pagina - 1) * $usuariosPorPagina;
                    // Creamos la busqueda SQL con una prepared statement
                    $sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare($sql);
                    //Datos necesarios para la paginación
                    $sentencia->execute([$limit, $offset]);
                    //Devolver los resultados como objetos.
                    $usuarios = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    // Para obtener las páginas dividimos el conteo entre los usuarios por página, y redondeamos hacia arriba
                    $paginas = ceil($conteo / $usuariosPorPagina);
                    //Si no obtenemos resultados mostramos mensaje
                    if ($conteo == 0) {
                        echo "<h2 class='err'>No se han encontrado resultados.</h2>";
                    } else {
                        //Imprimimos la cabecera de tabla
                        echo "<table class='tablaBusqueda'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Correo electrónico</th>
                        <th class='matr'>Matrícula</th>
                        <th class='rol'>Rol</th>
                    </tr>";
                        //Imprimimos los resultados de la busqueda
                        $contadorResultados = 0;
                        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {
                            $contadorResultados++;
                            echo "<tr>
                            <td>$usuario->cod_usuario</td>
                            <td class='nom'>$usuario->nombre</td>
                            <td>$usuario->correo</td>
                            <td class='matr'>$usuario->matricula</td>
                            <td class='rol'>$usuario->rol</td>
                            <td><input type='radio' name='radioBorra' value='" . $usuario->cod_usuario . "' /></td></tr>
                        </tr>";
                        }
                        echo "</table>";
                        /* Bloque nav para la paginación */
                        echo "<nav class='pagBuscar'>
                    <ul class='paginacion'>";
                        //Si la página actual es mayor a uno, mostramos el botón para ir una página atrás
                        if ($pagina > 1) {
                            $pag = $pagina - 1;
                            //Pasamos los parámetros de la página y de campo de busqueda por la URL
                            echo "<li>
                                <a href='./buscaUsuario.php?pagina=" . $pag . "&codigo=" . $_REQUEST["codigo"] . "&nombre=" . $_REQUEST["nombre"] . "&matricula=" . $_REQUEST["matricula"] . "'><span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span></a>
                            </li>";
                        }
                        //Mostramos enlaces para ir a todas las páginas. Es un simple ciclo for
                        for ($x = 1; $x <= $paginas; $x++) {
                            echo "<li class='";
                            if ($x == $pagina) {
                                echo "active>";
                            }
                            //Pasamos los parámetros de la página y de campo de busqueda por la URL
                            echo "'>";
                            echo "<a href='./buscaUsuario.php?pagina=" . $x . "&codigo=" . $_REQUEST["codigo"] . "&nombre=" . $_REQUEST["nombre"] . "&matricula=" . $_REQUEST["matricula"] . "'>$x</a></li>";
                        }
                        //Si la página actual es menor al total de páginas, mostramos un botón para ir una página adelante
                        if ($pagina < $paginas) {
                            $pag = $pagina + 1;
                            //Pasamos los parámetros de la página y de campo de busqueda por la URL
                            echo "<li>
                                <a href='./buscaUsuario.php?pagina=" . $pag . "&codigo=" . $_REQUEST["codigo"] . "&nombre=" . $_REQUEST["nombre"] . "&matricula=" . $_REQUEST["matricula"] . "'><span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span></a>
                            </li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                        //Mostramos la información de lo que se está mostrando
                        echo "<div class='infoPaginasBuscar'>";
                        if ($pagina == $paginas) {
                            echo "<p>Mostrando";
                            echo $conteo - $contadorResultados + 1 . "-" . $conteo . "de" . $conteo . " usuarios</p>";
                            echo "<p>Página " . $pagina . " de " . $paginas . "</p>";
                        } else {
                            echo "<p>Mostrando " . $contadorResultados * ($pagina - 1) + 1 . "-" . $contadorResultados * $pagina . " de " . $conteo . " usuarios</p>";
                            echo "<p>Página " . $pagina . " de " . $paginas . " </p></div></nav>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "<input id='borraUsuario' type='button' onclick='borrarUsuario()' value='Eliminar' Name='borraUsuario'/>";
                    //Eliminamos el objeto que contiene la conexión a la BBDD para cerrarla
                    unset($base_de_datos);
                }
            }

            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['radioBorra'])) {
                //asignamos el valor del radio a la variable

                $usu = $_POST['radioBorra'];
                echo "<script>alert ('Usuarios eliminados: $usu')</script>";
                //Creamos el objeto con la conexion a la BBDD y la sentencia de borrado
                $sentencia = $base_de_datos->query("Delete from usuarios where cod_usuario = '$usu'");
                // mostramos un alert 
                echo "<script>alert ('Usuario eliminado')</script>";
            }
            ?>
        </main>
         </form>
        <!-- Incluimos la plantilla del pie de página -->
        <?php include("pie.php"); ?>

    </body>

    </html>
```

También dejo el código de js de la función `onclick='borrarUsuario()`:

```javascript
function borrarUsuario() {
      if (confirm('¡¡¡ATENCIÓN!!!\nVa proceder a la eliminacion de uno o varios usuarios,\nsi continua también se eliminaran las reservas asociadas a estos usuarios.\n¿Desea continuar?')) {
        $('#busqueda').submit();
      } else {
        alert("No se han eliminado los usuarios seleccionados");
      }
}
```

Comment: cuando usas un radio button o checkbox, si este no se marco no se enviara el valor; estoy investigando al respecto para ver como lo hacen los framework y darte una respuesta completa y amplia para la comunidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si te sirve de ayuda sigue sin funcionar aunque me asegure de marcar un radio, creo que el problema reside en que al tratarse de un radio seleccionado sobre los resultados de la busqueda del formulario de busqueda, cuando la pagina se recarga al darle al boton de eliminar , se pierden los  checkbox o radio que hubiera seleccionado. No se si el problema es este, solo es una suposición que hago desde la poca experiencia que tengo.

Comment: si, ahora que lo mencionas es muy probable, entonces tienes que hacer algo para que al recargar la pagina de busqueda estos sigan seleccionados... tienes que investigar eso y desarrollar esa parte si, eso lo intentas y te sale algun otro error entonces nos dices en otro post para ver si te apoyamos...

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he encontrado el fallo aunque no entiendo el motivo. Al inspeccionar la página con el navegador me he dado cuenta de el value del input aparece vacío:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es el código original:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $usuario->cod_usuario ?></td>
  <td class="nom"><?php echo $usuario->nombre ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $usuario->correo ?></td>
  <td class="matr"><?php echo $usuario->matricula ?></td>
  <td class="rol"><?php echo $usuario->rol ?></td>
  <?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkBorra[]' value='" . $usuario->cod_usuario . "' /></td></tr>"; ?>
 </tr>
```

No entiendo porqué si que muestra el resto de datos como en la primera celda pero sin embargo no lo hace en el value. Incluso he probado forzando un value XXX

pero al inspeccionar sigue apareciendo vacío.

Alguna idea de como poder solucionarlo?

Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Fallo encontrado y resuelto. En el archivo JavaScript de este proyecto tenía este fragmento de código para que unos input de un formulario de registro modificaran sus campos al recuperar el foco:

```js
$("input").focus(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
    $(this).val("");
    $(".aviso").css("color", "grey");
  });
```

Lo cambiado por [type='text'],[type='email'],[type='password']

Perdón las molestias generadas y saludos